# .Net Webapi using Odata v4 and viewmodels

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api2, odata

I just started working with Odata and I must say I really enjoy it. $fetch, $select, $expand, etc.. is just amazing. However, I am not really understanding how to tie odata to viewmodels. One of the reasons I am interested in shaping the data is because odata does not seem to easily support hiding/ignoring properties. I also do not believe in presenting more information to the client than is needed at that time.

For example you create a user object that includes password field.

```
public class User
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName{ get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; } 
}
```

But you need to provide a list of your users. Naturally you would not want to list the password field.  You can programmatically exclude that field doing something like:

```
var users= modelBuilder.EntitySet<User>("Users");
 users.EntityType.Ignore(usr => usr.password);
```

Or you could decorate it in the class itself:

```
[IgnoreDataMember]
public string Password { get; set; } // Not visible in the EDM
```

The problem is both of these affect the model in a global fashion, if I understand what is happening correctly.

So, if the user needs to change their password for example, they now have no way to do that using the User class.

It also seems that if I implement viewmodels I will break a lot of the functionality that odata provides.

Like I said I am new to odata and am just having a hard time understanding how to shape the data for the client.

Any guidance that can be provided would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, it is better not to hide the password field, as it is a valid user's field. What you need is to introduce/define permissions in your data model. So that objects/fields are shown to authorized users only.